# Multiple MySQL Nested Selects

Tags: mysql, nested, multiple-tables, sql

Hi there I wonder if someone could help, I am having a complete mental block.

I have this select statment that works perfectly, however I now want to check the results (FirstName and Surname) against another table to find out more details about them.  I can't for the life of me figure how to do that.

```
SELECT `FirstName` ,  `Surname` , MobilePhone
FROM users
WHERE NOT 
EXISTS (

SELECT PhoneNumber
FROM Orangedata
WHERE users.MobilePhone = orangedata.`PhoneNumber`
)
```

This select returns me a list of records (Name and Mobiles) that I want to run another select with.

The Result looks like

```
FirstName Surname Mobile
```

I want to run my next Select that says

```
Select *
from Table 3
WHERE FirstName = FirstName from previous select AND WHERE Surname = Surname from previous select.
```

The overall result I am looking for is

Give me all the details (from Table 3) for a user that does not have any record in table Orangedata

Its effectively three nested selects (I think) and I just can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table3.* FROM    
      table3 
      JOIN 
      (SELECT `FirstName` ,  `Surname` , MobilePhone
      FROM users
      WHERE NOT 
      EXISTS (
           SELECT PhoneNumber
           FROM Orangedata
           WHERE users.MobilePhone = orangedata.`PhoneNumber`
      )) as b  
ON (table3.FirstName = b.FirstName AND table3.Surname = b.Surname))
```

Or something like this